# How do you make an object inside nested json with python?

Tags: python, json

How do you make an object inside nested json with python?

example

```
{
    friends:{
        john:{
            height:182
        }
    }
}
```

How would I for example make another object inside john named weight and set it to 60kg (just an example) with python.

Comment: This is neither a runnable Python code example nor valid JSON syntax. Please show an actual [mre]. You would have to use some code along the lines of `data['friends']['john']['weight'] = 60`, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'friends':{'john':{'height':182}}}
data['friends']['john']['weight'] = 60
```

Output:

```
{'friends': {'john': {'height': 182, 'weight': 60}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
In [1]: x = {
    "friends":{
        "john":{
            "height": 182
     }

In [2]: x["friends"]["john"]["weight"] = 60

In [3]: x
Out[3]: {'friends': {'john': {'height': 182, 'weight': 60}}}
```